# C++ debugging in Eclipse Luna

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-luna

I manage to start my application, but the command arguments are no passed to it.

That's my "Debug Configuration" comics:

[image: Main tab]
[image: Arguments tab]
[image: Debugger tab]
[image: Source tab]
[image: Common tab]

I tried all ways I ciuld imagine to start it (Run as, Run configuration, Bug Icon mentioning my debug cfg name...), and it runs but never with my args. It shows this:

[image: Variables panel]

When I was waiting for "xml" and "CRM.lsa" arguments.

Another things which make me confused are:
- whether I specify Working Dir on "Arguments" teb right (it's the dir with input file CRM.lsa)
- whether I should change "Standard Input and Output" settings on "Common" tab (I wan't the executable to take file CRM.lsa as input and ouput, if any, to console or another file)

Hope for some advice, Eclipse is so hardcore sometimes.

Thx!

Comment: what do you expect to see? Everthing looks good at the first glance. Did you try to output argv[1] and argv[2]?

Comment: @chrmue, I expected to see correct values in variables panel.

Probably, I got too used to MSVS fine-crafted output from my past Win experience.

Now I see, it's all ok - at least at test project.

Comment: the value is correct, you see argv[0] which is the name of process you started. Try to output argv[1] and argv[2] on the console (or as expression in the "Expressions" tab

Comment: I can't find my cout output in console now. Which one should I switch to? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you're right that the value is correct - it just shows pointer addresses instead of meaningful info.

Now I strive to see my output in console while debugging.